# Periodic point near Hyperbolic fixed point

Tags: dynamical-systems

This question is the last exercise of chapter 2 in Lan Wen`s Differential Dynamical system. (Exercise 2.12)

let $E$ a finite-dimensional normed vector space and $p \in E$ be a hyperbolic fixed point of $f$. Given any positive integer $m$, prove there is a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ such that any period point of $f$ in $V-{p}$ has a period greater than $m$.

here $U$ is open subset of $E$ and  $ f: U\longrightarrow E $ is $C^k$  and local Diffeomorphism.

Comment: Your question does not specify what $f$ is.

Comment: Sorry, I am editing now, here $U$ is open subset of $E$ and  $ f: U\longrightarrow E $ is $C^k$  and local Diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by contradiction.

Suppose this is not true. You will find a $M$ and a sequence of point $p_k \to p$ of periodic point converging to $p$ with period less than $M$.

Taking a sub-sequence, they can have the same period $m \leq M$ so they are fixed for $f^m$. Notice that $p$ is still a hyperbolic fixed point of $f^m$.

Now taking again a sub-sequence, they can approch $p$ in the same direction, that is $\frac{p-p_k}{\| p -p_k \|} \to v \in E$.

Computing the differential in the $v$ direction for $f^m$ with this sequence will give you a $0$ and this cannnot be since it is suppose hyperbolic.

Comment: Dear @EtienneBfx thanks for your answer. I can not understand your fourth paragraph. Do you take two sub-sequence that approch $p$ in the same direction? and How?

Comment: Sorry I am not fluent in english and that might be confusing. You should take only one sequence that approch $p$ in a given direction. If you note $x_k=\frac{p-p_k}{\| p- p_k \| }$ then all $x_k$ are in the sphere of vector of norm $1$ which is compact. You take a sub-sequence converging to an accumulation point.

Comment: @EtienneBfx Would you mind explaining more about your answer? Why could we take a subsequence of $p_k$ with the same period $m$?

Comment: All $p_k$ are periodic point with period less that $M$, so there is only a finite number of possibilities for their period $0,1,2,...,M$. So there is at least one subsequence of $p_k$ with the same period.